# How to ensure a RF module is indeed FCC compliant as advertised?

Tags: rf, bluetooth, radio, wifi, fcc

Suppose a buyer buys RF modules from China and wants to ascertain that they're indeed FCC compliant as advertised. I'm guessing that this should be a fairly common issue since Chinese manufacturers/suppliers don't have the best reputation in the world, so I wonder if there's any common practice to avoid getting cheated.

1. Even when the FCC ID can be verified, there are good chances that the parts have been swapped out for junk.
2. Even though the FCC website has the internal photos, it's difficult to eyeball the discrepancies.

How could the buyer ensure that what they get is what was tested by the FCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy direct from the manufacturer.

Likely ok: [PTR9018 directly from Xuntong Technology](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2-4G-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Wireless-module-NRF51822-32-bit-cortex-M0-256K-flash-Freeshipping/130096_1358287487.html)

Unknown: [PTR9018 from reseller](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/nRF51822-module-PTR9018-Working-frequency-2_1687703687.html)

For larger deals, you may want to study up on "miàn zi", and develop some relationships in person (ie: travel to Shenzhen).  It is useful to have friends/acquaintances who already do business there, who can introduce you and/or act as your representative.

Most assuredly do not suggest that you want to avoid being cheated!  Ask for documentation with your purchase which includes certificate of FCC compliance, and give a non-offensive reason such as "because it is required by government agency in USA" (it may well be, for example for medical devices).

Comment: Right. But manufacturers could just as well be dodgy, right? Is it common for (small) companies to rerun the EMC tests? The FCC test report is on the fcc.io website - is that actually good enough?

Comment: @JohnMunroe: I think a small company would rarely choose to rerun EMC tests; especially for a part with "modular approval". You're covered by the vendor-supplied documentation whether that is correct or not, it's still a good faith effort on your part.

Comment: @JohnMunroe: Larger manufacturers are very unlikely to be dodgy; much bigger problem is counterfeit parts made by small no-name outfits which can (sometimes unknowingly) be sold by resellers as the real thing.  The pcbs can be seen to be different on close examination.

Comment: Most manufacturers in China are small and just sell through taobao (Chinese eBay). Hardly any track record or reputation to speak of.

Comment: @KR: most manufacturers are probably small but the guys that get FCC approvals are a bit bigger (10-100M/year?).   My impression: Xuntong, Huamao, RFstar etc (just calling out some familiar ones) do larger volume than western equivalents like RFduino or BlueGiga.

Comment: @AlexI I think this manufacturer is relatively tiny, as this is the first module branded under them and the only FCC approved device.

Comment: Buy from a reputable distributor, and keep all your records.